# Multiplayer game using pygame

Tags: pygame, multiplayer

I just created a simple pong like game using pygame. But I want to make it multiplayer so that I can play with my friend. But how can I sync the data? Anyway which I could do it?

Comment: Do you mean multiplayer on the same computer (i.e. shared keyboard and mouse) or do you mean networked between two computers on separate computers?

Comment: @GlennMackintosh two computers.

Comment: @GlennMackintosh two computers which initially have no connection in between. It would be great if I could deploy it on web.